# why multiplying the two series together give this as the coefficient of x^r?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> **If $c_1,c_2,.....c_n$ are the coefficients in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$, when n is a positive integer, prove that**
>
> $c_0-c_1+c_2-c_3+........+(-1)^rc_r=(-1)^r\frac{n!-1}{r!(n-r-1)!}$

Here is the solution (it's an image).

[image]

**I am having trouble understanding why multiplying the two series together give this as the coefficient of $x^r$?**

Can anyone explain how we get this?

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here one has to  prove that 
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{r} (-1)^k {n \choose k}= (-1)^r {n-1 \choose r}$$, there are several methods to prove this sum. But let us take the route mentioned by OP.
$$(1+x)^n=C_0+C_1 x+ C_2 x^2 +C_3 x^3+ ......+C_{r-3} x^{r-3}+ C_{r-2} x^{r-2}+ C_{r-1} x^{r-1}+ C_r x^r+....+C_n x^n....(1).$$ Here $C_k={n \choose k}.$
The infinite G.P is written as
$$(1+x)^{-1}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+....+(-1)^{r-2} x^{r-2}+ (-1)^{r-1} x^{r-1}+(-1)^r x^{r}+....+...~~~(2)$$
Now we multiply one term from (1) and one from (2) so that product of the two terms has $x^r$ in it, so
$$(1+x)^{n} (1+x)^{-1}=[C_0 (-1)^r ~ x^r + C_1 x (-1)^{r-1} x^{r-1}+ C_2 (-1)^{r-2} x^{r-2}+....+C_r x^r]+......\text{many other terms}$$
$$\implies (1+x)^{n-1}=(-1)^r[C_0-C_1 +C_2 -C_3+.....+(-1)^r C_r] x^r+---\text{many other terms}.$$
Thus,  $$(-1)^r[C_0-C_1 + C_2-C_3+.....+(-1)^r C_r]= (-1)^t~S= \text{co-efficient of}~ x^r ~ \text{in}~ (1+x)^{n-1}= {n-1 \choose r}.$$
Finally, $$S=(-1)^r ~ {n-1 \choose r}$$

Answer (score 2):

It is convenient to use the  *coefficient of*  operator  $[x^r]$  to denote   the  coefficient  of  a series.

> We  obtain the coefficient of $x^r$ of $(1+x)^{-1}(1+x)^n$ in two different ways. At first we multiply out the terms.
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^r](1+x)^{-1}(1+x)^n}&=[x^r](1+x)^{n-1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n-1}{r}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In (1) we select the coefficient of $x^r$.

> Now we expand  at first the geometric series $(1+x)^{-1}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$ and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^r](1+x)^{-1}(1+x)^n}&=[x^r]\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^jx^j(1+x)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^r(-1)^j[x^{r-j}](1+x)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^r(-1)^{r-j}[x^j](1+x)^n\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^r\sum_{j=0}^{r}(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> Comparing (1) and (5) shows the claim is valid.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we expand the geometric series $\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^jx^j$.
- In (3) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$. We set the upper index of the sum to $r$ since other indices do  not contribute to $[x^r]$.
- In (4) we change the order of summation $j\to r-j$.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^j$.

**Supplement** regarding the alternating sum $\color{blue}{(-1)^r\{c_0-c_1+c_2-c_3+........+(-1)^rc_r\}}$:

- Recalling the product of two series $C(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^k$ with $A(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^j$ we can   interpret the multiplication with $A(x)$ as  transformation of the coefficients $c_k$
  \begin{align*}
  C(x)A(x)&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^j\right)\\
  &=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^rc_ka_{r-k}\right)x^r\tag{6}\\
  \\
  \color{blue}{c_r}\quad&\color{blue}{\to\quad\sum_{k=0}^rc_ka_{r-k}}\tag{7}
  \end{align*}
- A  special case of (7) is   to obtain the  sum  of the  first  $r+1$ coefficients of $C(x)$ by setting $A(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$. We obtain from (6)
  \begin{align*}
  C(x)\frac{1}{1-x}&=C(x)\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j\\
  &=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^rc_k\right)x^r\\
  \color{blue}{c_r}\quad&\color{blue}{\to\quad\sum_{k=0}^rc_k=c_0+c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_r}
  \end{align*}
- Another  special case of (7) is   to obtain the  *alternating* sum  of the  first  $r+1$ coefficients of $C(x)$ by setting $A(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$. We obtain from (6)
  \begin{align*}
  C(x)\frac{1}{1+x}&=C(x)\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^jx^j\\
  &=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^rc_k(-1)^{r-k}\right)x^r\\
  \color{blue}{c_r}\quad&\color{blue}{\to\quad(-1)^r\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^kc_k=(-1)^r\left\{c_0-c_1+c_2-\cdots+(-1)^rc_r\right\}}
  \end{align*}